# Big Data with Blaza and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh, blaze

I want to know if this approach would be an overkill for a project.
I have a 4gb file that obviously my computer cant handle. Would using Blaze to split the file into more manageable file sizes and open with pandas and visualize with Bokeh be an overkill?

I know Pandas has a "chunk" function but the reason i want to split them is because there are specific rows related to specific names that i need to analyze.

is there a different approach you would take that wont crash my laptop and doesnt require setting up Hadoop or any AWS service?

Comment: Your question is too vague to really be answered.  If you want to extract certain rows from the file, it should be possible to do that without too much trouble (e.g., by using the chunksize you mentioned and writing out your target rows to a separate file as you go through he large file).

Comment: This seems like a good application for [Dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/). Its interface is very pandas-like, but it can handle out-of-core computations.

Comment: *"I have a 4gb file that obviously my computer cant handle."*  That's not obvious at all.  What kind of data is in the file?  What processing do you need to do with the data?  How fast is your computer, and how much memory does it have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas chunking with `pd.read_csv(..., chunksize=...)` works well.

Alternatively [dask.dataframe](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) mimics the Pandas interface and handles the chunking for you.

Comment: WOAH @MRocklin, thanks! i was browsing your  website prior to submitting this question didnt think i would an answer from you, awesome!  The Pandas Categoricals article was great btw.